# how to resolve pending migration error in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-7

I have created a migration in which i mistakenly duplicate the columns of "created_at" , now my screen is displaying this error, after when i remove the duplication, the errror was also same before removing the duplication.

This is the terminal messages:

```
PS C:\Users\iamvee_k\Desktop\Rails Projects\blog> rails db:migrate
== 20231003192318 AddTimestampsToArticles: migrating ==========================
-- add_column(:articles, :created_at, :datetime)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: created_at
C:/Users/iamvee_k/Desktop/Rails Projects/blog/db/migrate/20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: created_at
C:/Users/iamvee_k/Desktop/Rails Projects/blog/db/migrate/20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: created_at
C:/Users/iamvee_k/Desktop/Rails Projects/blog/db/migrate/20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and this is the output screen:
[image]

Comment: Have to tried removing the `add_column(:articles, :created_at, :datetime)` line from the migration and re-runing the migration again?

Comment: no, i make another migration in which i tell it to remove that column @MarceloPaco

Comment: But the error is telling you that you can't make it because it already exists. `created_at` is created by default if you didn't specify to not create it.

Comment: @AfaqKhan but we see only one pending migration (only name and error text) in the question. You should delete this new migration where remove column and delete adding column in `db/migrate/20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb`

Comment: @MarceloPaco, no, it is not creating by default, you need specify `t.timestamps`

Comment: This is what the documentations says when generating migrations: `By default, the generated migration will include t.timestamps (which creates the updated_at and created_at columns that are automatically populated by Active Record).`

Comment: @mechnicov can you please let me know how can i delete that migration ?

Comment: @MarceloPaco you should read more carefully, this is in the context of `rails g model` command

Comment: @AfaqKhan with `rm db/migrate/your_file_we_don_t_know_how_called.rb`, probably it is the last file (after `20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb`)

Comment: yayyyyyyyy. ! thanks @mechnicov sir the error is gone now. thanks a lot

Comment: You should add migration file content to the question. Who knows, may be you even don't need this file if it is single change

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create_table`, e.g.

```
create_table :saving_transactions do |t|
  t.integer :value_in_cents

  t.timestamps
end
```

`t.timestamps` will create the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields for you, so leave it there but remove the extra `created_at` you added manually.

When you do, you have two choices:

1. If you don't care about losing the data you have you can use `rails db:reset`. This will drop the databases and run the migrations again (so make sure to fix the issue of having an extra `created_ at` before running the command)
2. If you don't want to lose the data you can use `rails db:rollback`. It will rollback the last migration and you can pass how many steps you want (in your case is 1, but you don't need to pass it) with `STEP`. After that just run `rails db:migrate` again.

For example:

```
rails db:rollback STEP=3 # => Rollsback 3 migrations
```

More infos here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back

Comment: when i roll back this error is know showing on screen:  
 ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
You have 2 pending migrations:
20231003190949_create_articles.rb
20231003192318_add_timestamps_to_articles.rb

Comment: actually i am a beginner on rails that is why i don't know much about it.

Comment: I suspect you have another `created_at` field that you are not aware of, it's probably coming from `t.timestamps`. Can you share your migrations? See my new edit :)

Comment: No problem! It's part of the journey, Rails does a lot for you, so it's easy to try to do it yourself and run into these problems. Keep it up!

Comment: sir here is the migrations code of both files:                                                                              class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class AddTimestampsToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :articles, :created_at, :datetime
    add_column :articles, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end

Comment: @AfaqKhan look at my answer

Comment: Please add it to the question so people can see it if they run in the same problem. So the problem is that you probably have a `t.timestamps` when creating `articles`. Please also share the creation of `articles` so we can help you :)

Comment: @Tallboy sir when i try to execute the reset command this error display on terminal:           
PS C:\Users\iamvee_k\Desktop\Rails Projects\blog> rails db:reset
Permission denied @ apply2files - C:/Users/iamvee_k/Desktop/Rails Projects/blog/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ apply2files - C:/Users/iamvee_k/Desktop/Rails Projects/blog/db/development.sqlite3

Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: OP problem is pending migration, don't need to rollback old migrations, just fix pending one

Answer (score 0):

You didnt show your migration file, but if you see the line `t.timestamps` in your original migration, then `created_at` is already created along with `updated_at`.

If you don't want BOTH `created_at` and `updated_at`, then delete the line and explicitly define a single one of them, for example `t.datetime :created_at`

After you change your migration, do the following (will wipe your local data):

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Locally you do not need to worry about rolling back or all that stuff. Just wipe the entire DB and keep starting fresh. Locally this is fine because thats the point of seed data, is to keep re-seeding your app and you wipe and clear the database each time you change the migrations. Theres no reason to keep adding migration files when the app isn't launched yet

if you are encountering this issue in production, then IMO i always just hand edit the database by hand because I hate hundreds of unnecessary migrations.

So in production I would basically make a commit locally of the migration changes I want, and mentally note them. Then open my production database in a GUI and modify them as I see fit, making them match the way the database looks locally in the same GUI. This is good for smaller apps that dont need a complicated audit log of every change.

Comment: Don't need to drop database. Removing the line in the pending migration is enough

Answer (score 0):

You have created new migration but not yet migrated to your DB, so just use

```
bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

If the above command doesn't works then use `rake db:migrate`